# SonarQube Not Working in Eclipse Luna

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, eclipse-luna, sonarqube-5.0

I am using Eclipse Luna downloaded from eclipse.org

I am using latest sonarqube 5.01

I am using java 8

Sonar Server is hosted at 192.168.1.23

When i am trying to connect to Sonar server using Eclipse plugin I am getting following error in The WorkSpace Logs:

Error In Console:

```
Unable to get version of server 192.168.1.23:9008: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 192.168.1.23:9008/api/server/index
```

Error in Workspace log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 192.168.1.23:9008/api/authentication/validate 
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852) 
    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:69) 
    at org.sonar.wsclient.connectors.HttpClient4Connector.newGetMethod(HttpClient4Connector.java:158) 
    at org.sonar.wsclient.connectors.HttpClient4Connector.execute(HttpClient4Connector.java:81) 
    at org.sonar.wsclient.Sonar.find(Sonar.java:49) 
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.wsclient.internal.SonarWSClientFacade.testConnection(SonarWSClientFacade.java:69) 
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.ServerConnectionTestJob.run(ServerConnectionTestJob.java:52) 
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122) 
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 192.168.1.23:9008/api/authentication/validate 
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848) 
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021) 
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChar(URI.java:3031) 
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3047) 
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588) 
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:850)
```

If i Hit " 192.168.1.23:9008/api/server/index" in google chrome i am geeting an XML Response 
and if i do 
curl 192.168.1.23:9008/api/server/index

I am getting HTTP Response Code 500

Sonar Server is on OS Ububtu 64 bit

If I host Server on system with Elementary OS this is working fine.
But if serves OS is Ubuntu it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `http://192.168.1.23:9008` instead of `192.168.1.23:9008` in your Eclipse SonarQube > Servers settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is the problem with the ruby version .make it use system ruby
"ruby use System"